# How to determine if $(1,0,1,1), (1,1,0,1) , (0,1,1,1)$ spans $\Bbb R^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I set up a system where

$a(1,0,1,1) + b(1,1,0,1) + c(0,1,1,1) = (1,1,1,1)$

(the standard basis of $\Bbb R^4$)
then I found that

$a + b = 1$

$b + c = 1$

$a + b + c = 1$
which implies that $a = c = 0,$ and $b = 1$.

is this not a solution ?
because for me this spans the $\Bbb R^4$ space, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: You need at least four vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: You've shown that there exists a linear combination that gives $(1,1,1,1)$, but to establish that the vectors span the entire space, you need to show that *every* vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a linear combination of the given vectors.

Comment: @user170231 so i have to replace (1,1,1,1) by (x,y,z,t) bascially, and then when i do this i find that the solutions are not consistent, so there is no solution, so it doesnt span R4, right ?

Comment: Right, and no solution will be found because of the reasons mentioned by the other users

Comment: Obviously, it is not a solution. Put $a,c=0, b = 1$ in the original equation, what do you obtain?

Answer (score 2):

The span of $n$ vectors is a subspace of dimension at most $n$. Hence three vectors span at most $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of vectors $\{v_i\}_i$, you can discover the span space $\mathcal{R}$ by echloning the matrix

$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1^\intercal \\
\vdots \\
v_m^\intercal \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The rank of matrix $V$ i.e. $\mbox{rank}(V)$ is the span space dimension.